# Multer super slow upload after recieving post request with images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Hello I'm on a (ReactJs Node Mysql Express) stack, my website has an events tab which the admin could upload to it events.
Each event has a cover photo, inner photos, Title, and a brief text.
So I send this whole form in a single post request (is it good?)

```
var fileUpload = multer({ storage:storage,
limits:{fileSize:150*1024*1024}
})
```

```
const multipleUpload = fileUpload.fields([{ name: 'coverPhoto', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'innerPhotos', maxCount: 30 }])
```

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, files, cb) => {
    cb(null, '../client/build/imgs/events')
  },
  filename: (req, files, cb) => {

    cb(null, files.originalname)

  }
})
```

The server does recieve the request perfectly but after multer receives the photos it takes so long to move them to the fs and the reverse proxy would send a 524 error that it took so long knowing that the format is webp and the photos are so small in size.

Any idea why is it taking so long?
I tried to move to formidable but I couldn't figure how to retrieve multiple input fields with multiple files in it ( I only succeeded in sending one input not multiple inputs)

Thank you

Comment: Add storage code.

Comment: @Inder I added the code, please check it , thank you

Comment: Met with same issue. Have you tried 2.x? the received file buffer changed into a file readable stream. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer/v/2.0.0-rc.4